# Failed to install the browsers - Playwright Automation tool

Tags: playwright

I'm getting the below error while installing the browser binaries in playwright using the command - ' npx playwright install'. Error is as below:

Downloading Chromium 115.0.5790.24 (playwright build v1067) from https://playwright-verizon.azureedge.net/builds/chromium/1067/chromium-win64.zip
Error [ERR_SOCKET_CLOSED]: Socket is closed
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
at Socket._writeGeneric (node:net:920:8)
at Socket._write (node:net:942:8)
at doWrite (node:internal/streams/writable:411:12)
at clearBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:572:7)
at Writable.uncork (node:internal/streams/writable:351:7)
at ClientRequest._flushOutput (node:_http_outgoing:1140:10)
at ClientRequest._flush (node:_http_outgoing:1109:22)
at onSocketNT (node:_http_client:906:9)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
code: 'ERR_SOCKET_CLOSED'
}
Failed to install browsers
Error: Failed to download Chromium 115.0.5790.24 (playwright build v1067), caused by
Error: Download failure, code=1
at ChildProcess. (C:\Data\Playwright\node_modules\playwright-core\lib\server\registry\browserFetcher.js:95:16)
at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)

Can anyone help in this regard.

Comment: Are you able to download chromium manually from https://playwright-verizon.azureedge.net/builds/chromium/1067/chromium-win64.zip?

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the response.
I could download it by clicking on the link, however little stuck at the point on where to place the downloaded file (Which folder under playwright-code of node_modules) and about execution of first script.

Thanks in advance

Comment: See also GH issues: [#14616](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/14616), [#20863](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/20863)

Answer (score 3):

This error is because of the proxy server is bloking the npm to download the chormium browser exe file. to over come this download the chromium exe manually from the follwing link,
[1]: https://playwright-verizon.azureedge.net/builds/chromium/1067/chromium-win64.zip

And place the chrome-win folder inside the follwing path ms-playwright\chromium-1084(chrome-win)

C:\Users\abc4abc\AppData\Local\ms-playwright\chromium-1084\chrome-win\chrome.exe

Answer (score 0):

If it is because you are behind a proxy and you cannot disable it, you could download the browser manually and launch it in one of these ways by specifying path of browser in `executablePath: './yourpath'`:

In playwright.config:

```js
import {defineConfig} from '@playwright/test'

export default defineConfig({
    // ...
    projects: [
        {
            name: 'Chrome web',
            use: {
                browserName: 'chromium',
                launchOptions: {
                    executablePath: './yourpath'
                }
            }
        }
    ]
})
```

Or launch the browser manually in the test:
In testfile:

```js
test('Setup', async () => {
    const browser = await chromium.launch({
        executablePath: './yourpath'
    })
    const context = await browser.newContext()
    const page = await context.newPage()
    //...
})
```