# I am getting browser install failed error while running playwright scripts

Tags: playwright

I am running this in company laptop. Why am I getting this error?

```
Downloading Chromium 121.0.6167.57 (playwright build v1097) from https://playwright.azureedge.net/builds/chromium/1097/chromium-win64.zip
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20) {
  errno: -4077,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}

Failed to install browsers
Error: Failed to download Chromium 121.0.6167.57 (playwright build v1097), caused by
Error: Download failure, code=1
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\231012~1\AppData\Local\Temp\playwright-java-1092935437511818853\package\lib\server\registry\browserFetcher.js:91:16)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:294:12)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to install the browsers - Playwright Automation tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76611076/failed-to-install-the-browsers-playwright-automation-tool)

Comment: See also GH issues: [#14616](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/14616), [#20863](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/20863)